Determining possible onsets according to the Maximum Onset Principle
I'm using this link for reference. In simple terms, the MOP states that the onset of each syllable must be "as long as possible". So, for example, connect: /(kə)(ˈnɛkt)/, each syllable has the longest possible onset.
My question is: how can I determine which onsets are possible and which ones aren't? The link I've provided uses extra as an example, but I don't understand why */kstr-/ is not a possible onset.

Incidentally, it has been claimed English syllabification depends on principles other than the maximum onset principle: https://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/syllabif.htm

Which onsets are allowed isn't part of the Maximum Onset Principle, but a separate set of rules: the language's phonotactics. These rules allow /sT/ in English (spot, stick, skid) but not /Ts/ (pseudo-, tsunami, xenia lose their initial stops when borrowed), for example.
Unlike (some claims about) the Maximum Onset Principle, these rules are not universal; they differ by language. Greek allows /ps/ and /ks/ but not /ts/. Japanese allows /ts/* but not /ps/ or /ks/.
* (Oversimplifying for the sake of example; it's generally analyzed as an affricate rather than a cluster in Japanese, but then again, so are the English "presigmatized" stops, according to some authors!)

Thank you. Do you know of a source for these rules, in particular in English?

@agaminon Any good grammar should describe 'em. For a language as well-studied as English, Wikipedia often has a decent synthesis of the literature.

As Draconis said, the answer to this question depends on the language. The basic method is to look what consonant sequences can occur at the start of words in the language. For example, the word fleece is evidence that syllables in English can start with /fl/. If we had words that started with /kstr/ in English, that would be evidence that this could start a syllable. Since we don't have words of this form, this is instead evidence that /kstr/ cannot start a syllable in English.
This method is based on two assumptions: that a word can be pronounced by itself as a complete utterance, and that any utterance can be divided exhaustively into syllables. The second assumption is controversial, and so this method may not always produce correct answers.
For example, Latin words can start with /sp/, /st/, /sk/, such as spondeo, studeo, scio. But when one of these sequences occurs in the middle of a Latin word, certain evidence (stress patterns, the meter of poetry, and future sound changes) indicates that the sound /s/ is syllabified as a coda rather than as part of an onset (e.g. the Latin words hospes, noster, piscis seem to be syllabified as [ˈhos.pes], [ˈnos.ter], [ˈpis.kis]).
One solution to this sort of conflict between facts and the hypothesis of the Maximum Onset Principle is to introduce another hypothesis, the existence of "extra-syllabic consonants" (consonants that either don't belong to any syllable, or that are outside of the "core" structure of a syllable). Non-syllabic consonants are sometimes described as occupying an "appendix" found at the start or end of a word. Some sources that discuss extra-syllabicity: Stemberger and MacWhinney 1984, Duanmu 2008, Chapter 3
Returning to the examples of spondeo, studeo, scio, we could say in this kind of analysis that these don't actually start with /sp, st, sk/ as onsets, but instead start with extra-syllabic /s/ followed by onset /p, t, k/.
If we accept extra-syllabicity, then the criterion of what sequences can start a word is no longer an absolute guide to what sequences are possible syllable onsets. We then get into a lot of theory-specific assumptions: other relevant methods can include examining word-internal and word-final consonant sequences, and using the idea of "sonority" as a means of judging what syllable onsets are probable or improbable.
Even with extra-syllabicity, the absence of a particular sequence word-initially remains valid in general as a form of negative evidence, although it is subject to limitations like other forms of negative evidence.
